# python List is not defined error not sure how to define the List

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

```
def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1: List[int], nums2: List[int]) -> float:

    concat = sorted(nums1 + nums2)
    median = concat[len(concat) //2] if len(concat)%2 ==0 else (concat[len(concat) //2]                             +concat[(len(concat)+1)//2])/2
    return median
```

The error code is following:

```
> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-1-d7029d4b625d> in <module>
> ----> 1 def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1: List[int], nums2: List[int]) -> float:
>       2 
>       3     concat = sorted(nums1 + nums2)
>       4     median = concat[len(concat) //2] if len(concat)%2 ==0 else (concat[len(concat) //2]                            
> +concat[(len(concat)+1)//2])/2
>       5     return median
> 
> NameError: name 'List' is not defined
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `list`? If you didn't `List` would seem to be a class.

Comment: I never see that grammar type before def findMedianSortedArrays(self, nums1: List[int], nums2: List[int]) -> float:

Comment: It looks like you want to use the types available in `typing`

Comment: from typing import List

Answer (score 7):

Just add the import `from typing import List`

Comment: No, absolutely not, you can definitely use type-annotations in Python. The OP is trying to use the type annotations provided in `typing`

Comment: fixed @juanpa.arrivillaga